# Error when Passing a DataTable from vb.net to a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datatable

I have a stored procedure that receives a table, but whenever I make the insert I get this error:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

I create a table as type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Example AS TABLE
(
  Id_Exmp          int, 
  Discount_Amount  Money
)
```

I have a stored procedure that takes a datatable as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_Exmp
    @datatable dbo.Example READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.destination_table(column_list)
        SELECT column_list 
        FROM @datatable;
END
```

This is the code I have in VB.net:

```
Function Example(ByVal dtTable as datatable)
    Try
        ConexionSQL = New SqlConnection(IniciaConexion)
        Command = New SqlCommand("SP_Exmp", ConexionSQL)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        'Parametros a Utilizar
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datatable ", dtTable )

        ConexionSQL.Open()
        If Command.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
        ConexionSQL.Close()
        ConexionSQL.Dispose()
        Command.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MensajeError(ex, "Error")
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: The answer is in the definition of `dtTable` (which you haven't posted). If you look at the error, you have a datatype in `dtTabe` that is varchar (basically a string) when it should be numeric (money or numeric or decimal). Probably to accomodate the $ sign, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Actually I use more complex name for the SP, When I create the dtTable a Use a function the executes any query and I deside if I want to return a DataTable or a DataRow as example: Dim DtTable as datatable = Exec_Query(Query:="Select...", LRw:=false), Lrw=Logic Row to determine if a Want a datarow or datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. `Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datatable ", dtTable )`

You need to set its SqlDbType:

```
Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datatable ", dtTable).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

---

2. Dispose your command before the connection, or even better use Using pattern:

```
Using ConexionSQL = New SqlConnection(IniciaConexion)
    Using command As New SqlCommand

    End Using
 End Using
```

---

3. Instead of the Money DataType, try changing your SQL DataTable to have a second column of Decimal and your .Net Datatable to have a Decimal, eg:

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
dtTable.Columns.Add("Id_Exmp", typeof(int));
dtTable.Columns.Add("Discount_Amount", typeof(decimal));
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP is currently using some kind of char/string datatype for Discount_Amount but we won't know until they post it

Comment: When I create the dtTable a Use a function the executes any query and I deside if I want to return a DataTable or a DataRow as example: Dim DtTable as datatable = Exec_Query(Query:="Select...", LRw:=false), Lrw=Logic Row to determine if a Want a datarow or datatable –

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was the problem, the main issue was the order how I create the dtTable, in order to fill correctly the table type, I most create the column with the same order on the type, as an Example.

Dim DtTable as datatable = Exec_Query(Query:="Select Id_exm, Discoun..", LRw:=false)

for wherever reason I put in disorder, discount first and id second, I didn't pay attention to that,

then everything works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You have to open your connection.

```
ConexionSQL.Open().
```